# If I turn on IPN can I still redirect my button users to my custom response pages?

Tags: button, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am currently using email2db to read the emails PayPal sends regarding new subscriptions, payments, cancellations, etc.

Now that I have 6 different fork, including 1 from intl.paypal.com and one from paypal.co.uk it has become difficult to manage my db with email2db.

This is a production system. I want to know if the existing system will remain intact if I turn on IPN for testing and development. I need it continue to redirect the subscriber to my currently chosen thankyou page as included in my button code.

Is it safe for me to activate IPN?

Thank you,
Gordon L

Comment: IPN is server side stuff, it won't stop the emails.

Answer (score 0):

IPN is an entirely separate process from anything else you do. It's simply a notice you can have PayPal send when you get a payment or the status of one changes (i.e. chargeback etc). So it's safe to use with any payment process.